# ng-click updating $scope but not showing changes on the view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-ng-show

The following is my code..once i update the $scope variable, the model changes as expected even on inspecting the DOM but the view doesn't update. I have tried everything to get my view to show  up with no luck. Kindly assist.

**The code**

```js
//Initialize our Angular Application
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("inputController",function($scope,$http,$interval){
 
 $scope.views ={
  login_screen : false,
  search_screen : false,
  picture_screen : false,
  txloss_screen : false,
  emptloaded_screen : false,
  kd_screen : false,
  tat_screen : false,
  info_screen : false
 };



 

 //show correct view
 $scope.showView = function(view){
  $scope.views[view] = true;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid mainWrapper" ng-controller="inputController">
  
  ...
  <li><a href="#"  ng-click="showView('search_screen')">Search</a></li>
  
  ...
  
  <div class = 'row search_screen' ng-show="{{views.search_screen}}">
  ...
  </div>
  
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ngShow` doesnt need `{{}}` - it already expects an Angular expression:

```
ng-show="views.search_screen"
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm